# How do I "trigger" the external script file loaded from a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I successfully loaded a script into an existing page by bookmarklet.
(Can tell my a success js request seen in firebug)
The next step is to make the script run.

This is what my external script looks like.

```
javascript: (function () {
    alert('hello world');
}
```

and I don't see the alert. Missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not called and you have a syntax error (missing closing bracket `)`). You can make it an immediate executed function:

```
javascript: (function () {
    alert('hello world');
}())
```

**Update:** If you are actually injecting a script tag into the head via the bookmarklet, then you don't need to have `javascript:` in the file.

Comment: …and he doesn't need `javascript:` in an external file, as in this case he'll merely define a label by doing so.

Comment: It's an inspiration from here

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Sure, but I was not sure because of the bookmarklet. If he is loading a JavaScript file and injecting its code, then yes, he does not need it.

Comment: @Moe: You don't think I'm clicking on a link with 'mafia' in the URL, do you?